# How to put an SVG symbol in my rules-based symbology?

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, visualisation

I have added a points layer in which I have to put different SVG icons, according to the column level.

So far so good, the separation is according to the level using a default symbol, but I want to change this default symbol to be an SVG symbol.

```
my_rules = ( ('INICIAL','regexp_match("NIVEL",\'INICIAL\')','#B18904'), ('PREESCOLAR','regexp_match("NIVEL",\'PREESCOLAR\')','#00FF40') )
symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(vlayer.geometryType()) 
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRendererV2(symbol)
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
for label,expression,color_name in my_rules:
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color_name))
    root_rule.appendChild(rule) 
root_rule.removeChildAt(0)          
vlayer.setRendererV2(renderer)
```

I am trying to create a symbol `QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2`,
but I do not know how to use it within the rules-based symbology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like the following which creates a dictionary of properties for the svg and then changes the default symbol layer using the [QgsSymbol::changeSymbolLayer()](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbol.html#a972e1adc272c966ce3341d5265d5573a) method:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor

vlayer = iface.activeLayer()
my_rules = ( ('INICIAL','regexp_match("NIVEL",\'INICIAL\')','#B18904'), ('PREESCOLAR','regexp_match("NIVEL",\'PREESCOLAR\')','#00FF40') )

svgStyle = {}
svgStyle['name'] = 'path/to/icon.svg'
svgStyle['outline'] = '#000000'
svgStyle['size'] = '15'
symbolLayer = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayerV2.create(svgStyle)

symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(vlayer.geometryType()) 
symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbolLayer)

renderer = QgsRuleBasedRendererV2(symbol)
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
for label,expression,color_name in my_rules:
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color_name))
    root_rule.appendChild(rule) 

root_rule.removeChildAt(0)
vlayer.setRendererV2(renderer)
```

---

Example using "Arrow_01.svg":

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you.
I understand better how it works QgisSymbol :: changeSymbolLayer ()

Comment: @MarisolPrado - Most welcome, glad it helped :)